# Firebase for half and SQL for another half

Tags: firebase, crm, google-cloud-firestore, web-sql

I have built an app using firestore as we are interested in the realtime updates portion of things. However,we are not building a website that has CRM component where a lot of reports will be generated. The contents of that CRM are all new. There is only one report that would need firebase data as well as the new data (you can say 1 report out of 20).
I was thinking of building the CRM backend off mysql DB? Do you recommend to go with this approach or shall I do the CRM in the same firebase/firestore db?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a real-time backend database for your CRM, then the Firebase RTDB / Cloud Firestore would be ideal for this.  I'm not sure why you'd want to add a mySQL component, unless you are going to create some reports that require complex joins.  However, if your data is modelled correctly, this also shouldn't be an issue.

Take a look at this video to get a better understanding: [What is a NoSQL Database? How is Cloud Firestore structured? - Get to Know Cloud Firestore Ep.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ)

Comment: Hi Jason, The reason is these are customized reports. So I am afraid  I model the db in nosql and everthing is good. Then 2 months later and the client ask me for another complex report which the model does not meet. While in Sql, you can pretty much build any report by connecting the dots. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. We do something similar, where 99% of our data comes from Cloud Firestore, but we also copy some data to BigQuery for custom reporting